# WP All Import creates duplicate product attributes

Tags: attributes, wpallimport

I'm using WP All Import to import new products from an XML, or update them. The import works perfect, but I noticed that some attributes are double. They have been created again, after first import.
Maybe for new items. I checked XML file and it is normal.

I want to import toners and I'm using an attribute for color (`Χρώμα` in greek) and now i have 2 different attributes named `Χρώμα` with the same colors. Looking for CYAN color, I found 5 products in the first attribute and 11 products in the second one.

[image]

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Here is the xml from one product:

```xml
<product>
<id>1077</id>
<sku>TON-CLP320BK</sku>
<name>
Συμβατό Toner TON-CLP320BK για Samsung, CLT-K4072S, Black, 1.5K
</name>
<barcode>5202705407213</barcode>
<manufacturer>PREMIUM</manufacturer>
<descr>
<p>Συμβατό Toner TON-CLP320BK για Samsung, CLT-K4072S, Black, 1.5K</p><p></p><p>Συμβατά μοντέλα : </p><p>CLP325<br/>CLP320<br/>CLP320N<br/>CLP325W<br/>CLX3185FN<br/>CLX3185FN<br/>CLX318<br/>CLX318FN<br/>CLX3185FW<br/>CLX3185W</p>
</descr>
<availability>1</availability>
<dim1>40.0</dim1>
<dim2>9.5</dim2>
<dim3>18.5</dim3>
<weight>0.791</weight>
<tax>0.000</tax>
<stock_indicator>20</stock_indicator>
<minimum_quantity_to_order>1</minimum_quantity_to_order>
<RRP>15.00</RRP>
<url>
https://www.data-media.gr/product_det.asp?catid=263&subid=329&prid=1077
</url>
<thumb>
https://www.data-media.gr/photos/TON-CLP320BK.jpg
</thumb>
<image>
https://www.data-media.gr/photos/max/TON-CLP320BK.jpg
</image>
<volume>7030.000</volume>
<courier_weight>1.786</courier_weight>
<in_offer>0</in_offer>
<guarantee>12 μήνες</guarantee>
<group>
<id>4</id>
<name>Εκτυπωτές & Toner-Ink</name>
<category>
<id>263</id>
<name>Toner - Ribbon Μελάνια</name>
<subcategory>
<id>329</id>
<name>Toner</name>
</subcategory>
</category>
</group>
<filters>
<filter>
<name_id>9</name_id>
<name>Για Brand</name>
<value_id>8</value_id>
<value>SAMSUNG</value>
</filter>
<filter></filter>
<filter></filter>
<filter></filter>
</filters>
<price>10.16</price>
<price_without_offer>10.16</price_without_offer>
<retail_percent>20</retail_percent>
<retail_price>15.12</retail_price>
<vat>24</vat>
<pp>0</pp>
</product>
```

Comment: Can you share your XML? Would also help if you created a sandbox and shared login credentials for it: https://www.wpallimport.com/debug

Comment: Hello, did you find any solution? I have the same issue.. 
I guess "Auto create Terms" does not need to be checked..
Furthermore, the Attribute Name, should be exactly the same like the one you have already created in "Attributes" of WC. for example (inside WP All Import):
Color  {filters[1]/filter[5]/value[1]}
Thus, my problem is that I change the value of an attribute and does not chage it.